# Is it possible to change the name of a column in a query table in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have made a query table using a combination of local tables and other queries in Microsoft Access. Two of the columns in this query have the same name, is this possible to change in query designer?

Comment: Just add an example of your desired output. It would be clearer.

Comment: My desired output is to change the name of an existing column in a query table. Two columns in my query table have the name List_ID, and I want to change it to Product_List_ID.

Comment: In SQL you can use `AS` to rename your columns at run-time. `SELECT List_ID AS Product_List_ID FROM table_name;`. I'm not sure how closely MS Access follows SQL standards as I have not used it in decades.

Comment: As noted, many a time  when you join in tables,  you find "many" columns will have the same name. For example, every table like to have a PK column name of ID. This tends to not be a problem since you normally put the tableName.ID (the table qualifier) before the column name. However, as noted, simply use ColumnName as SomeName in the sql view, or in the query designer put   SomeName: ColumnName to create a different name, or what is normally called a alias.

Answer (score 5):

Add `MyNewFieldname:` before the field name. On the query designer that would be at the very left of the top line. Make sure you add it, not replace what is already there.

Or in SQL view use 'AS MyNewFieldName` after the field you wish to alias/rename.